# How to attach two suction hose pipes with different radii?

Tags: piping

I have two suction hose pipes, one of smaller radii from my washing machine, and another of large, which goes to a drain. What would be the best way to connect these two pipes?

Comment: The Home Improvement site is a much better fit for this question.

Comment: What's the actual situation & what pressures are involved? If it's a washing machine situation, a simple screw ring clamp usually suffices.

Comment: Tip: hoses will be specified by inner and outer **diameter**, not radius. It's easy to measure a diameter.

Comment: Look into what a P trap does, and what a stack does for plumbing.  Depending on where in this setup you have those, you may need to implement differently.  If it is all at the drain, and you are sure the hoses will empty into this drain rather than allow fluid to flow back into the washing machine, you may just need to have a sealed connection.  If you are lucky, an off the shelf coupler may exist for your hose sizes.